# Laravel Update Method is not Working as Expected

Tags: database, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm updating two fields for a records by using the following the code:

```
$companyPlan = CompanyPlan::whereCompanyId($companyId)->first();
$companyPlan->update(['plan_id' => $planId, 'next_plan_id' => $planId])
```

What it does is that it updates the `plan_id` field but not `next_plan_id`.

Both the `plan_id` and `next_plan_id` are in the $fillable array of the model.

It really is a strange behavior but I'm unable to know the reason why this is so.

```
protected $fillable = ['plan_id', 'next_plan_id'];
protected $hidden = [];
```

Comment: Since you are working on only one model: did you try setting the parameters explicitly and then save();?

Comment: Shouldn't your where be `::where('company_id', $companyId)`

Comment: @Kjell you mean update() method wouldn't work with one model? If this is what you are saying then why does it only updates plan_id and not next_plna_id not matter I change their position or order.

Comment: @Jonathan sorry, I didn't get what you said

Comment: There is a difference btw your update and the one suggested by @Jonathan: Your's gets the Model from the database into PHP, updates it and saves it back to DB; @Jonathan's code does run the update directly on the DB. The ```update``` method of the Model does nothing else than ```$this->fill($attributes)->save($options);``` - so you could also try this or even harsher: ```$this->forceFill($attributes)->save($options);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
CompanyPlan::where('company_id', $companyId)->first()
    ->update(['plan_id' => $planId, 'next_plan_id' => $planId]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, but this doesn't work.
Please note: plan_id is updated, but next_plan_id is not getting updated.

Comment: Do you get the expected value when you `dd($planId);` before the update?

Comment: yes, the 'plan_id' field is updated as expected, but the 'next_plan_id' doesn't get updated as expected.

Comment: I'm asking if you can see the value prior to the assignment though

Comment: yes, I can see the value with `dd($planId)`, and the `plan_id` field also gets updated, but the `next_plan_id` is not going to get updated.

Comment: `$planId` is not an object, it's mere a variable containing an int value

Comment: Ah yeah of course. Well the only thing I can see is that your fillable isn't being respected or your variable isn't. Have you tried setting `$next_plan_id ` manually as a copy of the former? That would at least tell us that fillable works and something else is at play.

Comment: you are right, I've manually added a new record using `fill()` method but the `next_plan_id` is not filled, while it is in the `$fillable` array, What do you think can be the reason?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the code structure around the model and how your fillable declaration was written, maybe you could update the question with those details

Comment: @MKJ can you please update on what has happened. If I've helped then please up-vote. If I've helped you found the problem, then please confirm and I will update my answer

Comment: The problem is not resolved but at least you helped me to understand that the problem is that some how $fillable property is not getting respected by laravel. You can include it in your answer, I'm up-voting you. Thanks for

Comment: But please do modify your answer.

Comment: @MKJ thanks ^_^. But can you confirm that this was fixed by addressing the fillable property? If we need to, by all means put back to unresolved - but will need you to update the question with how you defined the class that contains the fillable property

Comment: Actually, the `next_plan_id` field was added as a change in table, then I added this field name in the $fillable property, but when you asked me to add a record manually with fill() method, it made me clear that something is wrong with the laravel when it reads the $fillable property.

Comment: In that case, you would need to update the question with those critical clues, otherwise the question is eligible for closure as there's no way anyone could figure that out without leading questions about your table schema. I can't ethically update my answer to include this without it being reasonable for me to make those conclusions from the question itself, so can't update the answer unless those details are included >_<

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this, like **Kjell** said in comments:

```
$companyPlan->plan_id = $planId;
$companyPlan->next_plan_id = $planId;
$companyPlan->save();
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but don't you think it's lengthy as compared to the update() method.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because your table doesnt have any primary keys, so eloquent cant update it properly( **since it uses the primary key for updating a single model instance** ).

You should select the row by its unique attributes and update it on the same query, like this:

```
CompanyPlan::where('company_id', $companyId)
    ->update(['plan_id' => $planId, 'next_plan_id' => $planId]);
```

By eliminating the first() method, you are doing your work in only one query:

```
"UPDATE company_plans WHERE company_id = $companyId". *
```